# Table layout width is igonred CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

Hello Im trying to set fixed width for my table.

My problem is that the browser (chrome) ignores the width I set.

My code:

```
<div class="class_table"><table border="1" id="classes_list">

**MY TABLE CODE**

</table></div>
```

CSS

```
.class_table
{

font-size: 20px;
margin-top:35px;
margin-left: 25px;
position:absolute;
width:15px;
table-layout: fixed;
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the code now im using with image to show that its not working.

The HTML:

```
<head>

<?php

require_once('calssesHelper.php');

session_start();

$classesHelper = new ClassesHelper();

echo $classesHelper->getClasses($_SESSION['gym']);

?>

</head>
```

The php:

```
echo  '<div class="class_table"><table border="1" id="classes_list">';  

echo '<tr>
    <th>Class id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Teacher</th>
    <th>Place</th>
    <th>Message</th>
    <th>Users</th>
</tr>';

$count = 0;

while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    if ($count % 2 == 0)
        echo '<tr class="row_color_one_class" id="'.$id.'"><td>'.$id.'</td><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$date." ".$time.'</td><td>'.$teacher.'</td><td>'.$place.'</td><td>'.$message.'</td><td>'.$this->countUsersInClass($id)."/".$max_user.'</td>

        <td><button type="button" id="'.$id.'" onclick="removeClass(this.parentNode.parentNode, \''.$gym.'\')" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="images/program/trash_small.png"></button></td>

        <td><button type="button" id="'.$id.'" onclick="editClass(this.parentNode.parentNode)" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="images/program/edit_small.png"></button></td>

        <td><button type="button" id="'.$id.'" onclick="classUsers(this.parentNode.parentNode)" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="images/program/users.png"></button></td>

        </tr>';
    else
        echo '<tr class="row_color_two_class" id="'.$id.'"><td>'.$id.'</td><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$date." ".$time.'</td><td>'.$teacher.'</td><td>'.$place.'</td><td>'.$message.'</td><td>'.$this->countUsersInClass($id)."/".$max_user.'

            <td><button type="button" id="'.$id.'" onclick="removeClass(this.parentNode.parentNode, \''.$gym.'\')" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="images/program/trash_small.png"></button></td>

           <td><button type="button" id="'.$id.'" onclick="editClass(this.parentNode.parentNode)" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="images/program/edit_small.png"></button></td>

            <td><button type="button" id="'.$id.'" onclick="classUsers(this.parentNode.parentNode)" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="images/program/users.png"></button></td>

        </td>



        </tr>';

    $count++;
}

echo '</table></div>';
```

The CSS:

```
.class_table
{

font-size: 20px;
margin-top:35px;
position:absolute;
width:15px;
max-width:15px;
}

.class_table > table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see my result as far more the 15px

Comment: Ok, fixed but still not working

Comment: You're applying the styling to the div, not the table. Apply the same styling to the table and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/H4E8v/

Comment: Maybe my problem is that I echo this table from php?

Comment: No, the problem is that you're styling the div, not the table.

Comment: You'll probably need `word-break:break-all;`

Comment: @dasdasd Are you trying to set the width of the entire table or the individual cells? I can see that the Message column is longer, are you trying to get them all the same size?

Comment: I want that the entire table width will be max 15px

Comment: word-break:break-all; worked for me..

Comment: Yes, that will do the trick. You should also add `overflow:hidden`, and the `-ms-` browser specific property for the `word-break`. I have edited my answer to show you how you would use it.

Answer (score 0):

add a width to your table should work

```
.class_table>table{
  width: 100%;
}
```

it will fit the container

Comment: I would recommend using `.class_table table` in cases like this, it is supported by a bigger range of browsers.

Comment: this is not releavant, it depend on your project.it's just a matter of css designing, and > selector is supported massively,

Answer (score 0):

`table-layout: fixed;` should be added to your table and not your div.

you can do that by adding this class:

```
.class_table > table {
     table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle to show you:

http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/5b33P/

By using `table-layout: fixed;`, you do not need to set the width of the table, it will be as wide as it's container (100%), which is currently `width:15px;`.

If you have long content in your table which is causing it to stretch, there are a couple of things which you should do. Firstly, add something to break up and long words. Next hide any content which it too large to fit in the narrow cell. Here is a new class which you can add to achieve that:

```
.class_table > table td {
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and here is an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/5b33P/1/